# schema.rb got mysteriously changed into another file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, git

Using rails 3.2.8 ruby 1.9.3 p362.

There is something seriously amiss with my rails app. After so many db issues with an app, I STARTED FROM SCRATCH - read: rails new < new app name>

And started adding scaffolds and models. All in the past hour or so.

Then I tried to migrate a model called Product and I got the "Mysql2::Error: Table 'products' already exists" message when I ran rake db:migrate

Lo-and-behold my schema.rb file transformed itself into the mess of a file I had on my old app (on a different folder).

How can this happen? And how can I fix it?

Also, how often should I be pushing to git? I pushed once before building 2 new models and I already have a mess in my hands.

Help, please!

Comment: Did you clean up the old database for migrations from your older app / create a new database for the new app?

Comment: Turns out I didn't do that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Cool! Have posted my comments as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you clean up the old database for migrations from your older app / create a new database for the new app? Looks like it is the older database which is causing the issues.

You can go to your mysql prompt, and do a `drop database database_name;` and recreate an empty database using `create database database_name`.